How to check active subscription of In App Purchase in Flutter
I have implemented In-app-purchase using in_app_purchase, Flutter 3.19.5. Now I want to check User's Auto-renewable subscription from server side.
What is the best way to check User's current Auto-renewable  subscription plan from backend side (backend side - PHP)? Thanks in advance.
